# Test Flight - Yellow Dot - Waiting For Review

Tags: ios, build, review

I have just uploaded a new version of an App to Test Flight.

Is that all I have to do now until it is reviewed by Apple?

I have never used Testflight before and don't want to wait a week to find out I need to submit it for review or something.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It will go through a "preliminary" review, it's typically pretty quick (< 24 hours), but it only effects "public beta testers", you should be able to release to "internal testers" immediately (from memory).  When you release it to the App Store, it will go through another review, because, apple

Comment: Whenever you add a new version number, it requires a testflight review that is usually about a day. All subsequent builds of that version # are instantaneously approved for testflight access.  We usually use a version number like 4.5.0 (major.minor.feature) and then track build #'s.  If you make a new version number with every build, you will have to wait for that review every single time.

Comment: You actually have to go to the App Store tab and change the version to the version you have uploaded to Test flight. Then you can submit it for review.